# MySQL - Problem Updating table with values from a second table

Tags: mysql, sql

### Background

I'm working on a DB that stores information about people in my town. The main table **Citizens** has all the info, but lacks the *DNI* row (think of it as the "*NIF*", an integer number unique for every person), and so I was tasked with updating that table with the DNI values from another one (**New_Data**). The challenge is to update the **Citizens** with the *DNI* field from **New_Data**.

Both table share the *id* field, which is formed by the full name + year of birth. I don't have permission to change the structure of any of these tables.

I'm using HeidiSQL to run the queries.

### Table structure (simplified)

**Citizens**:

- id VARCHAR(150)
- full_name VARCHAR (150)
- dni VARCHAR (10) -> this row is currently NULL for all values

| id | full_name | dni |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Carlos Juan Fernandez1976 | Carlos Juan Fernandez | NULL |
| Daniela Lucia Kaltz2001 | Daniela Lucia Kaltz | NULL |

**New_Data**:

- id VARCHAR (150)
- dni VARCHAR (10)

| id | dni |
| --- | --- |
| Carlos Juan Fernandez1976 | 21.123.123 |
| Daniela Lucia Kaltz2001 | 40.214.123 |

### The Problem

I've tried different queries from all over the internet and cannot for the life of my get it to work. Some examples include:

**Query #1**

```
UPDATE Citizens AS c
INNER JOIN New_Data AS n ON (c.id = n.id)
SET c.dni = n.dni;
```

Goes on an infinite loop until I stop it. Doesn't update any row.

**Query #2**

```
UPDATE Citizens AS c SET dni = New_Data.dni WHERE c.id = New_Data.id;
```

Throws error: "Unknown column New_data.dni"

**Query #3**

```
UPDATE Citizens, New_Data
SET Citizens.dni = New_Data.dni
WHERE Citizens.id = New_Data.id;
```

Similar to the second one but including New_Data in the UPDATE clause. Also goes on an infinite loop without results.

**Query #4**

```
UPDATE Citizens c
JOIN New_Data n ON c.id = n.id
set c.dni = n.dni WHERE c.id = n.id
```

Again: infinite loop.

### Funny stuff

If I run:

```
SELECT n.dni, c.full_name FROM New_Data AS n
INNER JOIN Citizens AS c ON (c.id = n.id);
```

I can see the DNI and full names of all citizens, but the same INNER JOIN doesn't work with the UPDATE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try indexing.  For this query:

```
UPDATE Citizens c JOIN
       New_Data n
       ON c.id = n.id
    SET c.dni = n.dni;
```

You want an index on `New_Data(id, dni)`.

Comment: Well, that did it. Apparently I needed to add the field *id* in both tables as KEY. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems your MySql session has the [safe-updates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates) option set.

In this case, you can't update (nor delete) records without specifying a key (ex. primary key) in the where clause. You can try:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

Or you can modify your query to follow the rule (use primary key in where clause).

I reproduced and tried your first query and it works.

---

EDIT for the *"SQL (1205): Lock wait timeout exceeded;"* error:

This can be caused because one query is locking one or more tables. You can run the command:

```sql
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

There you should see a table like [this](https://proyectoa.com/wp-content/uploads/hm_bbpui/3501/e0staqfe93kwx1d0794arbko4rlswnrb.png) (depending your interface).
In column 'state' you can see which processes are locked, and using the column id run:

```sql
kill [ID];
```

After that, your tables should be unlocked and your update query should run properly.

Comment: Nope, now I get the error "SQL (1205): Lock wait timeout exceeded;".
I've tried also updating only one record and still get an infinite loop:
UPDATE Citizens c
JOIN New_Data n ON c.id = n.id
set c.dni = n.DNI WHERE c.id = 'Carlos Juan Fernandez1976';

Comment: This can be caused because one query is locking one or more tables.

You can run the command:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

There you should see a table like this (depending your interface):
https://proyectoa.com/wp-content/uploads/hm_bbpui/3501/e0staqfe93kwx1d0794arbko4rlswnrb.png

In column 'state' you can see which processes are locked, and using the column id run:

```
kill [ID];
```

Comment: Yes, I've read about that and killed the process currently running.
Actually the problem as Gordon Linoff pointed out was that the id field needed to be a Key.
BTW, thanks for your help.